How to stop the double click to unzoom?
I am trying to disable "double-click to unzoom" behavior. I found this parameter in highlight:
highlight(on = NULL, off = "plotly_doubleclick")

but to no avail.
I want to double-click with right button to unzoom. Preferably, only one right click to unzoom.
Update
I have this part of interactivity that I need, that seems to override the way to do it.
This  function only runs through shiny. It will not run otherwise.
library(htmlwidgets)

 js <- "
    function(el, x, inputName){
      var id = el.getAttribute('id');
      var gd = document.getElementById(id);
      var d3 = Plotly.d3;
      Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
        function attach() {
          var coordinates = [null, null]
    
          gd.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            var xaxis = gd._fullLayout.xaxis;
            var yaxis = gd._fullLayout.yaxis;
            var bb = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = xaxis.p2d(evt.clientX - bb.left);
            var y = yaxis.p2d(evt.clientY - bb.top);
            var coordinates = [x, y];
            Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, coordinates);
          });
        };
  }
  "

onRender(js, data = "clickposition") 


I am not sure if it's possible to use right click to unzoom (at least not easily). Even if it was, that's a very confusing UI. What if someone wants to actually right click? I'd stick with scroll zoom.

Please see this thread for JS implementation: https://community.plotly.com/t/disable-double-click-unzoom/2630/4
In R, we can use plotly::config to change the configuration. You need to save your plot to an object and then render it with your custom configuration.
config(pltly_obj, doubleClick = FALSE)

Here's an example:
library(plotly)

plot_ly(na.omit(palmerpenguins::penguins),
        x = ~bill_length_mm, y = ~body_mass_g, 
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers") -> pltly_obj

## I would enable scrollZoom if I were to disable doubleClick reset
config(pltly_obj, doubleClick = FALSE, scrollZoom = TRUE)


Created on 2024-04-28 with reprex v2.0.2

I want to mark this a the right answer, but it just does not work for my case.  I have edited the question for more details

@PPenton Please read my comment on why right click is not very desirable (if possible) for zooming out.
